# how to store NSDictionary in NSUserdefaults and how can I retrieve from it

Tags: iphone

I am getting some info from web server like this.

```
970,
Aditya2,
B,
JNTU1,
"Ram@gamil.com"
```

I need to store these values and I need to retrieve it from there where I want.

I found NSDictionary is correct for this.

I need to save these values in NSDictionary.

How can I do this?

Comment: what does it have to do with NSUserDefaults... ?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

To store and then receive:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:myDictionary forKey:@"dictionaryKey"];
//...
NSDictionary * myDictionary = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryForKey:@"dictionaryKey"];
```

[Here's a link to the NSUserDefaults Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: If your wondering about the NSUbiqutousKeyStore class, you need to set your dictionary using setDictionary:forKey: instead of just setObject.

Comment: there is no setDictionary method in NSUserDefaults as i see