# Save UIScrollView position and restore when app opens again. (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, scrollview

I have an application where I have a UIScrollView *TheoryViewController* that is **640 x 9000**.

Seeing as it's so much content, **I want users to be able to dismiss the view (*TheoryViewController*), (or quit the app), and when they relaunch the app and open *TheoryViewController* , I want the ScrollView position to be at the last position again.**

I have looked for several options, but either they are deprecated or are in Swift.

I am running Xcode 8 and targeting iOS 8 SDK.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSUserDefaults - Saving UIImageView Position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17383897/nsuserdefaults-saving-uiimageview-position)

Comment: What did you try exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save the `contentOffset` in `NSUserDefaults`. Then when the view appears again, scroll to that position using `setContentOffset()`.

```
// Save.
NSUserDefaults* userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults setObject:NSStringFromCGPoint(self.scrollView.contentOffset) forKey:@"scrollViewOffset"];

... somewhere else in your code ...

// Restore.
NSUserDefaults* userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
CGPoint offset = CGPointFromString([userDefaults objectForKey:@"scrollViewOffset"]);
[self.scrollView setContentOffset:offset animated:NO]
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you possibly show me with code? I am fairly new to this.

Comment: @SamGuichelaar If this it, please select the answer :-)

Comment: @SamGuichelaar Graag gedaan! I'm Dutch too :-)

Answer (score 2):

Save current `offset` in `UserDefaults`

```
CGPoint tableOffset = [tableView contentOffset];

NSUserDefaults * userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults setObject:NSStringFromCGPoint(tableOffset) forKey:@"pointPosition"];
[userDefaults synchronize];
```

To scroll to saved position:

```
CGPoint thePoint = CGPointFromString([userDefaults objectForKey:@"tableOffset"]);
[tableView setContentOffset:thePoint animated:NO]];
```

Answer (score 1):

You also required contentSize, contentOffset , and zoomScale to get exact output

You can store all into UserDefault  and restore again  when required

Check here how you can handle with `NSUserDefaults` https://stackoverflow.com/a/4562488/4601900

```
 NSMutableDictionary *dict = [@{
                                          kZoomLevel : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", self.zoomScale],
                                          kRotationDegree :[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", self.rotationAngle],
                                          kScrollViewContentSize : NSStringFromCGSize(self.scrollViewPhoto.contentSize),
                                          kScrollViewContentOffset : NSStringFromCGPoint(self.scrollViewPhoto.contentOffset),
                                          }mutableCopy];
```

you need to restore it  this way

```
 if (dictMainData) {

    NSString *contentSize = [dictMainData valueForKey:kScrollViewContentSize];
    if (contentSize) {
        self.contentSize = CGSizeFromString(contentSize);
        self.scrollViewPhoto.contentSize = self.contentSize;
    }

    NSString *contentOffset = [dictMainData valueForKey:kScrollViewContentOffset];
    if (contentOffset) {
        self.contentOffset = CGPointFromString(contentOffset);
        self.scrollViewPhoto.contentOffset = self.contentOffset;
    }

    NSString *strZoomLevel = [dictMainData valueForKey:kZoomLevel];
    if ([strZoomLevel floatValue] > 0) {

        self.zoomScale = [strZoomLevel floatValue];
        self.viewBase.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(self.zoomScale,[strZoomLevel floatValue]);

        CGRect frame = self.viewBase.frame;
        frame.origin = CGPointMake(0, 0);
        self.viewBase.frame = frame;
    }

    NSString *strRotationDegree = [dictMainData valueForKey:kRotationDegree];
    if ([strRotationDegree floatValue] > 0) {

        self.rotationAngle = [strRotationDegree floatValue];
        self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(self.rotationAngle * M_PI/180);

        //[self rotateTargetPointsAsPerRotationAngle];
    }

 }
```